# How to know current time on publicly available ntp pool servers without logging into it?

Tags: linux, ntp

I've 2 endpoints (here PCs) with Linux OS versions connected to a publicly NTP Time Master (for e.g. **server 0.in.pool.ntp.org**). Time on those 2 Linux PCs are properly syncing with that ntp pool server. Even time is same on 2 Linux PCs. Perfect, everything is fine.

I've an unique requirement in testing to check whether -

- "***Network device shall sync their clocks to an NTP Server as per their configured NTP client settings.***"

Now I want to know - what **actual** time is on NTP Server (here it's server **0.in.pool.ntp.org**).

To know the time on Linux machine, I can run - `timedatectl` command after logging into Linux PC.

Since, **server 0.in.pool.ntp.org** is obviously a Public NTP pool server, of course anyone can't login simply.

How to know the time on publicly available NTP Pool Servers without logging in to that ?

Is there any command exist to fetch just the time/date from NTP Server, without logging into that?

It would help me a lot to provide objective evidence (as proof) between - time on those 2 Linux PCs and time on **server 0.in.pool.ntp.org** are SAME and I can PASS the test for NTP feature.

Comment: This makes no sense. Why do you care what is the time on the ntp server is running on?

Comment: Do you just want to see the time?  It is here, for example: 
 https://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/time/display-clocks/simpletime

Answer (score 0):

> How to know current time on publicly available ntp pool servers without logging into it?

Use NTP.

> what actual time is on NTP Server

The one reported via NTP running on that server.

> How to know the time on publicly available NTP Pool Servers without logging in to that ?

It's literally NTP is **the protocol** to exchange time information from one server to another. Use that protocol to get the time on remote server.

> Is there any command exist to fetch just the time/date from NTP Server, without logging into that?

Yes - literally any command that uses NTP protocol is just for that. There's also `clockdiff` command with `ICMP` timestamps. Pointless to use `clockdiff`, when you have ntp..

> time on those 2 Linux PCs and time on server 0.in.pool.ntp.org are SAME

I would say it's physically impossible for time to be "same" in two locations.

In your `timedatectl` output you have a `System clock synchronized:` line. Also `timedatectl show-timesync` will give you some more information about `systemd-timesyncd` operation. And `timedatectl timesync-status` has many more available data, like offset, delay, clock root distance, precision.